# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 even if using same java version to compile and deploy

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

It might look like an existing question.. But other answers did not helped me. :(

Here is what I am doing
1. In eclipse using JDK1.7 to build the war file from a Eclipse web project (Windows 8)
2. Copy it in an unix tomcat7 webapps folder. Unix also have java1.7. If I run java -version it says 1.7
3. Now run tomcat. It throws below error for a class
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Look at *exactly* how you're running Tomcat. I strongly suspect you're running it using Java 6. (Does your Tomcat startup log show that information? It's been a while since I've run Tomcat...)

Comment: @Jon.. Thanks !! I do not see anything in log.. Can you please suggest where can I look to see if it is using java 6.

Comment: Well I'd start off by adding diagnostics to however you're starting Tomcat - log exactly which binary it's running, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It might look like an existing question.. But other answers did not helped me. :(

It IS like an existing question.  I can guarantee it.

The problem is basically the same every time.  The code has been compiled with with Java 7 and you are running running it on an older JVM.  That's what the error message means.  Always.

So you need to figure out why the code is running on an older JVM.  And since the code is running in Tomcat, that means you need to figure out:

- how you are launching Tomcat, and
- why the Tomcat launch procedure / script is using an older JVM rather than the one you expect it to use.

This typically boils down to identifying and reading the launch script or scripts that are being used, and figuring out where their environment variables settings are coming from.

Comment: Thanks! But can you please suggest some ways to do these steps.

Comment: Do you know how you are launching Tomcat?

Comment: I am in ubuntu.. After you install tomcat it automatically create the launch file.. I am running using "service tomcat7 start"

Comment: Look for the tomcat init script in "/etc/init.d"

Comment: +1 and accepted.. Though Java -version was showing java 7.. Tomcat was using openjdk 6. That was the issue. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The message "Unsupported major.minor version" indicates you are running java in a jvm with a lesser version than the one used to compile the code. Note that Java is backwards compatible, so you can run java 6 on java 7, but not the other way around.

To verify the vesion of your tomcat, use this: ./version.sh

When I run it on my tomcat I get this:

```
<...>/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin# ./version.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.50
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.50
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.50
Server built:   Dec 19 2013 10:18:12
Server number:  7.0.50.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.32-47-server
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_17-b02
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Note the entry **JVM Version**

What can you do to fix the issue: Either compile your classes using the same version, or install a Tomcat that is of the latest version.

Comment: That script can / could be misleading.  It tells you what the JVM version would be if you ran catalina.sh by hand from that directory.  But when Tomcat is launched by the 'init' system (as is the case for the OP) the environment variables come from a different place, and could lead to a different JVM being used.  You really need to understand how Tomcat is being launched by the 'init' system.

Comment: I understand your point. But if the OP has installed Tomcat and hasn't changed any of the settings (as it seems in the post) then this could indicate what the version is. However, you are right, and the right thing to do would be to, for example, print the java version to the logs.

Comment: Also note, this is only telling you what version of Java is being used (which we can semi-infer from the original error message).  Neither the "version.sh" script or printing the version the logs really tell you why the JVM version is being selected / where the environment variable setting is coming from.  You really need to find and read the relevant scripts.